# Simple "facebook.php" is not working

Tags: php, facebook, html, facebook-php-sdk

I am fairly new to the PHP world and facebook integration. I am trying to connect my website to my facebook page to get the content, but a simple program seems to not working. I made sure to get the latest version of facebook code at github. Here is what I have in "test.php":

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <title>My Pictures</title>
    </head>
   <body>
   <a> hello 1 </a>
   <?php
   echo '<a> hello 2 </a>';
   include_once 'src/facebook.php';
   echo '<a> hello 3 </a>';
   include_once 'src/config.php';
   echo '<a> hello 4 </a>';
   $facebook = new Facebook(array(
       'appId'  => FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
       'secret' => FACEBOOK_SECRET_KEY,
       'cookie' => true,
       'domain' => 'uuu.com'
   ));
   echo '<a> hello 5 </a>';
   ?>

   </body>
```

Just some notes, I know the path for facebook is correct, I tried to put other files, and it worked perfectly, but with this I only see "Hello 1 Hello 2", so it looks like the facebook.php is failing at something, but I don't what, and don't know how to check what it is. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What do you get if you try to load `src/facebook.php` directly in the browser? Also, check your error logs.

Comment: are there any errors thrown, if so edit in?

Comment: turn on error reporting with `error_reporting(E_ALL)` else you may not get an error if error reportings too low, and change `include_once` to `require` require will spit out fatal error if its not found... bet your path is out..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   $facebook = new Facebook(array(
       'appId'  => FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
       'secret' => FACEBOOK_SECRET_KEY,
       'cookie' => true,
       'domain' => 'uuu.com'
   ));
```

do you have registered your facebook app in getting an id and the secret key?

Be also aware, the facebook communication might not work through localhost. But to be ensure, try to enforce the error output on your webpage through following codelines, so you're able to identify in more details why it is not working (post then the output as a follow up here, in getting a better support for solvement):

```
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick input. Yes, I have the correct APP_ID and SECRET_CODE. I added the following lines and it now prints: "hello 1 hello 2 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_OLD_FUNCTION or T_FUNCTION or T_VAR or '}' in /usr/local/pem/vhosts/285970/webspace/httpdocs/facebook/src/facebook.php on line 35" so I looked at the line 35 and it has "  public function __construct($config) ". Any idea what need to be changed?

Comment: A quick google search for the error was because my host was running PHP4 and PHP5 both, so I just turned off the PHP4 support, and all of items showed up correctly. Thank you.